# Are there any downsides to using unix_timestamp vs slot to time lock programs?

Tags: program, slots, clock, block-time

Let's say I want to restrict access to my program up until a certain time. Given some future time I can either:

- Use `Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp` to check if my future time has occurred yet
- Assuming each slot is ~400ms, predict which future slot will encompass my start time (and compare using `Clock::get()?.slot`

I know that there can be clock drift issues with both of these strategies, however using the `unix_timestamp` property seems a lot easier to reason about. Are there any downsides to using it (security or otherwise) instead of trying to predict the slot?

Comment: Very curious to hear someone in the know comment on this. My assumption after only a little pondering is that if "time" is semantically what you're after, then unix timestamp is strictly the better option, no downsides. And the converse would be true if all you cared about semantically was not time per se, but the number of possible state changes, number of elapsed epochs, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The two approaches are roughly equivalent in an ideal world, however,
unix_timestamp is based on [stake weighted median vote timestamps](https://docs.solana.com/developing/runtime-facilities/sysvars) with drift capped by slot time estimate from epoch_start_timestamp.

In other words, both will be at most equally wrong during major desynchronisation, while the unix_timestamp can be less affected by intermittent changes in slot time.